# Using facebook login and getting access to variables

Tags: php, facebook

I am incorporating facebook login into a website I am creating.

Once the user is logged in through facebook, what code is needed to access the users email, name, telephone number, etc?

I have my own system where they log in to the website and the code I have written allows me to check their information.

I am going to allow both methods of use and need to know how to get access to the code that pulls the user data from facebook once allowed by the end user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the [facebook documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/), it's very well documentated. They [use](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph) data [graphs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). You can search up about [OAuth](http://www.google.nl/#q=oauth+2.0+facebook+php+example) too.

Answer (score 0):

The code for each of the things you mentioned is a little complicated to be explained here, but basically you need to work with access tokens and the permission the user gives you.

Links for how this works [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and an example with basic permissions would be [this](https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor).